# How do I make a conditional that select only the element true - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I make a conditional that select only the element true? I have a condition to change the active state or not of a menu and I just want it to change if the element itself is true. Right now, as there is a true element, the condition is added to all the elements. I need to only add the class if the element is true, keeping false the other elements that have not been clicked.

```
    submenuClick(padre) {
        const { padreState } = this.state;
        const corriente = { ...padreState };
        const toggle = !corriente[padre];
        this.toggle(corriente);
        corriente[padre] = toggle;

        this.setState({
            padreState: corriente,            
        });
        if(corriente[padre] === true){
            this.setState({
                addClass: !this.state.addClass           
            });
         }
        console.log(corriente);
    }
```

Edit and add the code for class Menu, where I add the class to all the elements

```
class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        let activeClass = ['desplegable'];
        if(this.props.addClass) {
            activeClass.push('active');
        }
        return (
        <li key={this.props.id} className="list__item">
            <button
                title={this.props.menu}
                id={'mn-' + this.props.menu}
                className={activeClass.join(' ')}
                onClick={this.props.submenuClick}
            >
            <Icon icon="auriculares" className="ico-auriculares" />
                {this.props.menu}
            </button>
            {this.props.abrirSubmenu ? (
                <div id="sb-crm" className="submenu">
                    {this.props.submenu.map(hijo => (
                        <h3 className="nav--title">
                            <Icon icon="descargar" className="ico-descargar" />
                            {hijo}
                        </h3>
                    ))}
                    <ul className="list">
                        <li className="list__item">
                            {this.props.descripcion.map(tercerNivel => (
                            <a href={this.props.url} title={this.props.descripcion}>
                                {tercerNivel}
                            </a>
                            ))}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="content-bnt">
                        <button id="desplegar" className="btn btn--rounded" onClick={this.props.desplegarClick}>
                            <Icon icon="flecha" className="ico-flecha"/>
                            <Icon icon="flecha" className="ico-flecha"/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </li>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my response from the console log if i click in the second element (padre-44):

```
{padre-114: false, padre-44: true, padre-50: false}
```

I think you have to add something in my "corriente" condition, but I do not know how to do it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: you want to add an `active` class to item that is currently true?

Comment: Yes, I need to add a active class for the item that is currently true

Comment: where do you want to add the class?

Comment: This is my code: https://codeshare.io/5DJBB3 and I add the class in class Menu extends Component. Add the class is not the problem, the problem is that if i click in the toggle elements the class add in all elements. For that reaseon i think that i need the condition for a element clicked in the toggle

Comment: add the menu code to the question, so everyone can see it.

Comment: Ok Junius L., I have already edited it

Comment: I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the state value of the current `this.state.padreState['padre-' + datos.id]` which can either be true or false.

```
Menu
  key={datos.id}
  menu={datos.menu}
  submenu={datos.submenu}
  descripcion={datos.descripcion}
  url={datos.url}
  desplegarClick = {this.desplegarClick} 
  submenuClick={() => this.submenuClick('padre-' + datos.id)}
  abrirSubmenu={this.state.padreState['padre-' + datos.id]}
  addClass={this.state.padreState['padre-' + datos.id]} // here add current state of  padre
  />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again, Junius L. I thought that I only needed to modify submenuClick but I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

first of all,You don't need to check if true or not with === comparison. Just if(eleVal) is sufficient i.e the condition will be valid (will go to "if" block) only if the eleVal is true else will go in "else" block. If you want the code to execute only for selected element then you can right it in some "onclick" or equivalent trigger function than writing for all and just check for  selected elements "true/false" value